# How to subscribe to a topic using android studio (Firebase Cloud Messaging) in the MainActivity.java folder?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to follow the Firebase Docs for this using the code they have to subscribe to topics but I have no idea where to put it though--when I try to add it to the MainActivity.java as instructed, I'm getting a bunch of errors.

Here is my MainActivity.java file:

```
import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("weather")
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribed);
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribe_failed);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I'm getting these errors:

1. "Invalid method declaration; return type required"
2. "Cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseMessaging'" errors
3. "Annotations are not allowed here"

And many more--leading me to believe I'm doing this all wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to not be importing `FirebaseMessaging` yet. /See https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/java/MainActivity.java#L32

Comment: Thanks--after importing it it still gives me an error "Cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseMessaging'" in the actual import statement....I'm using capacitor if that makes a difference

Answer (score 1):

You have to put it in a method, like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // your firebase code here
    }
```

Comment: thanks this helps! still getting a bunch of errors though....mainly "Cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseMessaging'"....not sure if it's a capacitor issue or what's happening. Thanks

Comment: You need to add the import for a few things. Android studio will show you suggestions and add them automatically when you confirm.